# JradioButton that is in ButtonGroup to setSelected

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

I have two JRadioButtons: `SabiranjeradioButton` (which I put in ButtonGroup) and  `Dijeljenjerdbtn` (which I did NOT put in a ButtonGroup). I want to make a **Reset Button** so when I click the button the program should be as it opened.

The problem is that I tried to use the method `.setSelected(false)` to remove the select from the JRadioButtons but it **does not work** for the `SabiranjeradioButton` (which I put in ButtonGroup).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ButtonGroup does not let all of the RadioButtons to be unselected at the same time. You can clear the selection manually via the [ButtonGroup#clearSelection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection()) method.

> Clears the selection such that none of the buttons in the ButtonGroup
>   are selected.